# git-bash on windows returns logging

Tags: windows, git-bash

When running commands in git bash, a lot of extra info is added to the terminal. Why is this and how do I turn this off? Example below of output when enter is pressed:

```
  ++ __git_ps1
    ++ local exit=0
    ++ local pcmode=no
    ++ local detached=no
    ++ local 'ps1pc_start=\u@\h:\w '
    ++ local 'ps1pc_end=\$ '
    ++ local 'printf_format= (%s)'
    ++ case "$#" in
    ++ printf_format=' (%s)'
    ++ local ps1_expanded=yes
    ++ '[' -z '' ']'
    ++ '[' -z '4.4.12(1)-release' ']'
    ++ shopt -q promptvars
    ++ local repo_info rev_parse_exit_code
    +++ git rev-parse --git-dir --is-inside-git-dir --is-bare-repository --is-inside-work-tree --short HEAD
    ++ repo_info=
    ++ rev_parse_exit_code=128
    ++ '[' -z '' ']'
    ++ return 0
```

Comment: Can you try rerunning the above command using `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=0` followed by the command?  Does that make the extra output go away?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no that doesn't change the output

Comment: Could you share the content of your `~/.bash_profile`? When I have my misconfigured, I used to see extra output too

Comment: empty file. .gitconfig has some basic git configuration but nothing seems wrong there either